# No Code First Migrations When Deploying Via Visual Studio 2013

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I've written an API with no azure connection currently. I am now ready to publish this to Azure. In doing so, I assumed, as was the case with many other deployments, there would be an option for code first migrations. The website already exists, so when I log in I select my website in the drop down, but the screen I get looks like the below where the code-first migrations checkbox should be:

[image]

How do I correct this so that I can deploy with code-first migrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue. If this happens, then your publish profile is set to update the database schema, but not to allow code first migrations. I can't speak to why Visual Studio sometimes does this, but to fix it, you'll need to alter the xml file representing that profile. They can be found under the 'Publish Profiles' folder. Most likely, your `<PublishDatabaseSettings>` element will have an `<Object Type="Dbfx...etc.">` and possibly and `<UpdateFrom>` element. Get rid of those and replace the settings with the below.

```
<PublishDatabaseSettings>  
  <Objects xmlns="">  
    <ObjectGroup Name="Namespace.Models.YourDBClass" Order="1" Enabled="True">  
      <Destination Path="your-connection-string-goes-here" />  
      <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">  
        <Source Path="DBMigration" DbContext="Namespace.Models.YourDBClass, AssamblyName" MigrationConfiguration="Namespace.Migrations.Configuration, Assambly" Origin="Convention" />  
      </Object>  
    </ObjectGroup>  
  </Objects>  
</PublishDatabaseSettings>
```

Now clean and rebuild for good measure and you should be ready to go. Do note, if you do not delete the other pre-generated elements in the PublishDatabaseSettings element the schema will update on publish and you will likely have an error on your first attempt to hit your API and the migrations occur. In my case, and in most, it will be an 'X already exists' error, as the migrations are attempting to create tables that were already created with the schema update.

I was able to figure out the issue and correct it with the help of this article: http://www.dominicstpierre.com/2012/11/enable-code-first-migrations-check-box.html